# accessing to a field in get_object method django in UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I need to access to a specified field in a model in an UpdateView and then pass that variable to the url

```
class UpdatePredioCreditoView(UpdateView):
    model = CreditoPredio
    form_class = PredioCreditoEditForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'predio/edit/credito.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(CreditoPredio,predio_id=)
```

I have tried with

```
def get_object(self):
   self.object = self.get_object()
   return get_object_or_404(CreditoPredio,predio_id=self.object.pk)
```

but im getting:

> maximum recursion depth exceeded

urls:

```
url(r'^update/predio-credito/(?P<predio_id>[-_\w]+)/$', UpdatePredioCreditoView.as_view(),name='updateprediogeneral'),
```

Sorry for the spanish variables, my client ask it like this.

Comment: You're calling `get_object()` *inside* `get_object`, hence the recursion error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, sorry, i saw the error after post my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to fetch the `predio_id` from the URL, and use it to fetch the object. You can do that with the following:

```
def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(CreditoPredio, predio_id=self.kwargs['predio_id'])
```